# Duplicate form navigation elements, HTML ID's

Tags: html, forms, uniqueidentifier

I have a table displaying results from a database, and I am adding some paging/navigation buttons to it, such as 'prev', 'next', etc. These are being constructed for now as submit input buttons that are wrapped with a form tag and some hidden inputs to pass the needed querystring values back to the page itself, which means each form and element in the form should have an ID attribute.

Now, I'd love to add the navigation to both the top and bottom of the table, so I've modularized the navigation generation into a single routine I call whenever needed. This of course leads to duplicate form and element IDs in the page when there is more than one navigation bar included.

I've thought of passing some 'count' parameter to the routine so that when generating the HTML it could append that value to the IDs, and there are other solutions, such as using a global counter (ugly), etc, but I thought I'd poll the crowd and see what others have done in this situation.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: When the button is clicked and the form for the button submitted as a GET request, wouldn't I want/need to use the element's IDs to GET values from the elements as needed (from hidden input's that store other querystring values, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might have been some confusion it seems over what I was looking for, but in a nutshell, a simple way to avoid the duplicate ID issue when using a form-based paging solution that can be displayed multiple times on the same page (above and below tabular data, for example). My solution is to model it after the PHPMyAdmin paging, in that I simply remove the IDs for the form elements for now and reference the data being passed via the name attribute, which allows for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Of the solutions you have thought of thus far, I would suggest the tactic that you mention first in the last paragraph. Passing a query string variable and loading X number of records including the number passed (doing error checking of course to make sure that some sneaky user doesn't try to put random characters in the query string) would resolve your issue.

Another option (since you are obviously doing codebehind for loading from the DB) is to create a session variable and assign the value to *that* when the links are clicked and use it to generate the list.

For both instances, when the page loads you can take the current value being passed and add X (number of rows in results shown +1) and change the value passed by the links.

Comment: Sorry, my question is worded a little confusingly... I'm not asking about the querystring values themselves that handle the paging, but rather the HTML IDs that the paging navigation will use to send those values back to the page itself.

Comment: If all you are worried about is the ID of the page navigation, then ignore the page navigation IDs and focus on the value of the link. That would give you the "page" to go off of.

Example: The link's name may be "lnkDataPage2" but the value displayed is "2" for the page number. You can use the value instead of the id.

Comment: I'm not worried per se, but correct me if I'm wrong here: 1) HTML requires that element IDs be unique for a given page, and 2) to properly reference the data passed from the form, I'm going to need IDs (can't rely on name attribute alone, in the case of radio buttons, etc). With that in mind, and with the same navigation forms being displayed twice, generated programatically, how do I ignore the input element IDs and still have the generated HTML validate?

Comment: I'll elaborate on what I was referring to, I was merely referring to the value of which page you should be loading. As for the questions you asked in the last comment:

1) Yes, they need to be unique; however, there is a really simple solution for what you're needing. If you have two navigations, you can add an identifier to the ID names (such as if your navigation links names are "lnkDataPage2" now, you could have navigation "a" (the top navigation) and navigation "b" (the bottom navigation). Thus your top link for page 2 would be "lnkDataPage2a" and the bottom would be "lnkDataPage2b".

Comment: 2) You use the ids for finding the element and then grab the value instead of the id for picking up the page value (so you don't have to do a ton of parsing, looking for each and every page value through element ids).

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. So, say we have N navigation bars on a given page, with each of the navigation bars input elements (prev, next) having IDs prev1, next1 for the first instance of the bar, prev2, next2 for #2... prevN nextN for the nth instance. When the user clicks 'next' on the nth instance of the bar, nextN and prevN get submitted to the page in the GET array (for PHP), referenced as $_GET['prevN']. How do I know which index in the array to access for the value, other than say doing regex on (prev(\d)) and then testing the exstance of prev1, prev2, etc till I find a value?

Comment: I must prelude with the fact that I'm not a php programmer (php is not one of the tags in the question, so I haven't even been addressing server side stuff); however (in .Net terms), when you are capturing what element (or which navigation link on which group of navigation) you should be able to capture which control/element has created the postback. By doing this, you can identify which control/element has been used (it should return a string). In asp.net/vb.net, it would be something similar to this: "Dim ctrlname As String = Page.Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET")" Unfortunately I wouldn't

Comment: know the code for php (or if it was even possible) without digging a bit further. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Ok, I think I have [found something](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) for you to get the equivalent of the __eventtarget in php... maybe. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this... I've gone in another direction on the solution, basing it off of how PHPMyAdmin handles the duplicate navigation elements.

Answer (score 1):

I recently made a paginator myself, but approached it in a totally different way. I used php to generate the numbers, and each number (page) had a  tag with an href that was mywebsite.php?page=x. That way you can use a get method, grab the page number from the url, and loop through as many times as you want for the number of pages displayed.

As they say, there is more than one way to skin a cat. I prefer the url passing method because I can stay away from forms and ID's in their entirety, making it so that the paginator can go wherever I decide to slap it in (and however many times).

Here's a snapshot of how I went about generating it. Hope it gives you some ideas!

```
/*PAGE NUMBERS*/
        // ceil rounds a decimal up to the next integer
        $pages=ceil(($totalrows-1)/$tablesize); //we subtract 1 from total rows because it counts 0
        //(int) typecasts the $pages variable, so that it is divisible by an integer (ceil makes it a float)
        $pages=(int)$pages;
        //displays all the pages with their links

        //if page count is less than 7 (the full paginator), display all pages
            if($pages<=7){
                for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++){
                    print "<a class='pages";
                    //add class current_page if necessary
                        if($page==$i){print " current_page";}
                    print "' href='index.php?page=";
                    print $i. "'>"." $i</a> "."  "."  ";    
                }
            //if page count is more than 7
            }else{
            //if page # is less than 4, display pages up to 7, so that there are always 7 pages available (makes the buttons not jump around)       
                if($page<=4){
                for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){
                    print "<a class='pages";
                    //add class current_page if necessary
                        if($page==$i){print " current_page";}
                    print "' href='index.php?page=";
                    print $i. "'>"." $i</a> "."  "."  ";    
                }
            //if page # is less than 4 away from the end, display pages $pages-7
                }elseif($page>=$pages-3){
                    for($i=$pages-6;$i<=$pages;$i++){
                    //8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
                        print "<a class='pages";
                        //add class current_page if necessary
                            if($page==$i){print " current_page";}
                                print "' href='index.php?page=";
                                print $i. "'>"." $i</a> "."  "."  ";    
                    }   
        //if it's in between the ends, do this          
                }else{                          
                    for($i=1;$i<$pages+1;$i++){
                    //limit the number of visible pages to 7
                        if(($i>=$page-3)&&($i<=$page+3)){
                        print "<a class='pages";
                        //add class current_page if necessary
                            if($page==$i){print " current_page";}
                        print "' href='index.php?page=";
                        print $i. "'>"." $i</a> "."  "."  ";    
                        }
                    }
            }
            }
```

Comment: Interesting solution samuel. For my purposes this won't work, but have +1 it and bookmarked for possible future use.